# how do I install MonetDB on Centos 6.5?

Tags: centos, monetdb

I would like to install MonetDB on Centos 6.5.

MonetDB website describes how to install for Debian / Ubuntu / Fedora distributions.

I've a server on Centos 6.5 (and I'm not entirely sure to which Fedora distribution this should compare with).

Obviously I would like to install the latest binaries of MonetDB: I would rather avoid to install from source (unless strictly necessary).

How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: We now also provide CentOS RPMs: https://www.monetdb.org/downloads/epel/

<s>Since we do not provide packages for CentOS, I believe compiling from source is the easiest option.</s> I tried this on a CentOS 6.5 VM, the steps follow below. Simply download a tarball release (e.g. https://www.monetdb.org/downloads/sources/Oct2014-SP2/MonetDB-11.19.9.tar.xz) and then

```
sudo yum install gcc bison openssl-devel pcre-devel libxml2-devel
tar xvf MonetDB-*.tar.*
cd MonetDB-*
./configure
make -j
sudo make install
```

That should do it, you should be able to continue with http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/UserGuide/Tutorial from there. One final note, in the ./configure step, watch out for the line "sql is enabled" towards the end, if it is not there, it will tell you which dependency is missing. Usually, they can be installed using yum (libxy-devel packages).

Comment: The installation of all the missing libraries was far from trivial but I was successful in the end! Thanks.

Comment: Unless you need those extra libraries, they do not need to be installed. E.g. ```geos``` is only required if you want to use geospatial features or ```mseed``` if you want to read ```.mseed``` files.

Comment: my query is now a year old. I am grateful that MonetDB has now a Centos rpm: it makes for a much more pleasant developer experience :)